# How to give access to only one field by a record owned by other user

Tags: permissions, field-level-security

I have a field that will only be edited when the process is finished, but the record owned by a person A and will be edited by a person B. I tryed a lot of things, but not work. I can’t change de owd. There is a way this works?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE Community!!. `Field Edit` action can be controlled by Validation rules majorly for this kind of process based requirements. So if you new to Salesforce, Please give a look in the Validation rule trailhead. It's give some idea to you for this. 
Trialhead link: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/validation-rules

Answer (score 0):

Row-specific FLS is not a feature available currently on the platform. You could add all editable fields to a Validation Rule and check that, but depending on the field count this might not be possible.

What you could do is lock the current record and create a custom object to serve as a proxy, and do the updates with automation. So that when the user updates this proxy record - which contains only the information you want them to update on the original record - your automation (a flow) unlocks the original record and updates it on the user's behalf.